# Mostrar imagen desde la carpeta servidor y mostrarla en una tabla con datos de la base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que se envían datos mediante un formulario PHP a una base de datos MariaDB. Me gustaría me sugirieran cómo poder mostrar a modo de reporte la tabla con los datos de la base de datos y mostrar la imagen que se almacenó en la carpeta `images`.

El script de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect(
'localhost',
'root',
'',
'INVENTARIO'
);
if($conexion==FALSE) {
    echo('Error en la conexión');
    exit();
}

$resultado=mysqli_query(
$conexion,
'SELECT*FROM CONTRALORIA'
);  
if ($resultado==FALSE){
echo('Error en la consulta.');
mysqli_close($conexion);
exit();
}
?>

<table border="4" bgcolor = "#D6EEE2" >

<tr>
<th>Número de Inventario</th>
<th>Descripción del Bien</th>
<th>Número de Serie</th>
<th>Marca</th>
<th>Modelo</th>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Area</th>
<th>Condición</th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Fondo</th>
<th>Cuenta</th>
<th>Valor Factura</th>
<th>Valor Actual</th>
<th>Fotografía</th>
</tr>

<?php


while($fila         =
mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
    printf('<tr>');
    printf(
    "<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>",  
    $fila[0], $fila[1], $fila[2] , $fila[3], $fila[4], $fila[5] , $fila[6], $fila[7], $fila[8] , $fila[9], $fila[10], $fila[11] ,$fila[12], $fila[13]
    );
    printf('</tr>');

}
?>

</table>



<?php
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>

La ruta de la carpeta donde se almacenan los datos es la siguiente:
<img src="/Inventario/images/<?php echo $imagen; ?>" alt="" width="100px" />
```

Ésta es la base de datos:

```
MariaDB [INVENTARIO]> describe CONTRALORIA;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| num_inventario | varchar(15)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| desc_bien      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| num_serie      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| marca          | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modelo         | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| color          | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| area           | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| condicion      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fecha          | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fondo          | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cuenta         | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| factura        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| actual         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| foto           | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Sólo aparece la tabla pero no logro hacer que se muestren los datos almacenados en la base de datos junto a las imágenes almacenadas en la carpeta `images`.

Agradeceré mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Te recomiendo que te pases por [cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para iniciarte. ¿Podrías decirme si quieres que aparezca la imagen en cada fila de resultado asociado a cada registro de la base de datos o al final en un listado del contenido del directorio? Por cierto, para reproducir mejor tu problema es mejor usar `SHOW CREATE TABLE CONTRALORIA` que un `DESCRIBE`. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar si alguna respuesta te soluciona el problema? Si es así márcala como respuesta correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Necesito que aparezca en cada fila los datos del elemento con su respectiva foto si son 5 bienes deben de aparecer sus respectivas fotos en cada fila

Comment: ¿Probaste mi ejemplo? Eso es justo lo que hace.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo estas modificaciones:

- Usa `htmlspecialchars` antes de enviar el contenido de los campos de la base de datos al navegador.
- Por cada imagen comprueba si está vacía y si ésta existe.

En la modificación que he hecho he comentado cada uno de estos pasos:

```
<?php
/* Función de apoyo para convertir los campos en HTML */
function pasar_a_html(&$valor) {
  $valor = htmlspecialchars($valor);
}
/* Ruta relativa desde la posición del script PHP CON barra final
  para facilitar la concatenación */
$ruta_base = 'Inventario/images/';
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
    /* Convertimos a HTML todas las filas para poder enviarlas al
      navegador de forma segura */
    $html = $fila;
    array_walk($html, 'pasar_a_html');
    /* Si no hay imagen almacenada en la base de datos avisamos de ello */
    if (trim($fila[13]) != '') {
        /* Si existe la imagen la mostramos, en caso contrario avisamos de ello */
        if (file_exists($ruta_base . $fila[13])) {
            $html[13] = '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($ruta_base . $fila[13]) . '" />';
        } else {
            $html[13] = '<span style="color: red;">(imagen no encontrada)</span>';
        }
    } else {
        $html[13] = '(sin imagen)';
    }
    printf(
        "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><tr>",
        $html[0], $html[1], $html[2], $html[3], $html[4], $html[5], $html[6],
        $html[7], $html[8], $html[9], $html[10], $html[11], $html[12], $html[13]
    );
}
```

Como podrás ver en el `printf` sólo he proporcionado los datos que han sido pasados por `htmlspecialchars` y por cada fila detecto si hay y existe la imagen para mostrar una de las tres opciones:

- (sin imagen): En la base de datos no está configurada ninguna imagen (NULL o cadena vacía).
- (imagen no encontrada): En la base de datos hay una imagen que no está en el directorio de imágenes.
- Imagen: Si todo está correcto se mostrará la imagen en la celda correspondiente.

Comment: Hola Oscar Gracias por tu respuesta, añadí tus lineas a mi script y me apareció en la celda de imagen el texto de imagen no encontrada, verifiqué la ruta y pues no encuentro error en la ruta Inventario/images, que faltará?

Comment: O la ruta base no es la correcta (confirma que es esa ruta relativa a la localización del script) o no están las imágenes en el directorio. Si quieres pasamos a un chat para tratar el problema de manera más ágil.

Comment: ok mi nombre es Francesc Aburto en Facebook

Comment: Lo siento, no uso Facebook. En una hora y media llegaré al trabajo, estoy de camino, allí abriré una sala de chat aquí mismo, aunque creo que la reputación mínima para usar el chat era 15 o 20, no lo recuerdo. Luego miramos alguna forma de comunicarnos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: si quieres enviame tu email y te envio el proyecto completo

Comment: Avísame cuando estés por aquí, te pondré el email y borraré el comentario para que no se queden datos personales por aquí. ¿Tienes gmail? ¿Usas hangouts?

Comment: Hola estaré aquí enviandote mi email a las 11:00 AM, saludos ah y estoy en Gmail como Juan Francisco Aburto, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola deberías tener un campo donde guardar la ruta donde se aloja la imagen, y luego requerir ese campo con el dato de ruta.

Sería:

INSERTA JUNTO CON TUS DATOS, EL DATO DONDE SE ALOJA TU IMAGEN

$ruta = "carpeta_principal/imagenes/imagen.jpg";

Y luego recuperar ese campor de tu base de datos.

SELECCIONAR TODOS LOS DATOS, JUNTO A ESTOS DEBERÍA ESTAR LA RUTA.
$ruta = campo "foto";

EN CUANTO A TU CÓDIGO:

La ruta de la carpeta donde se almacenan los datos es la siguiente:

img src="/Inventario/images/php echo $imagen;" ...

-->
php
echo $imagen;
-->
¿Donde generas esta variable?

img src= " -esta barra esta de mas- */*Inventario/images/..." ...

En tu base de datos tenes un campo foto. Ese campo supongo que debería estar guardado la ruta donde alojas la imagen en la carpeta de tu proyecto.

Espero ser claro, si tenes alguna duda estoy atento. Si entendí mal tu consulta, espero que lo aclares.

Saludos.-

Comment: Hola @Facundo, bienvenido a la comunidad. Recuerda que las respuestas deben usarse para resolver los problemas que se plantean en la pregunta. Si tienes preguntas que hacerle al autor debes plantearlas como comentario. Sé que no tienes aún reputación suficiente (creo que se necesita 50) pero deberías esperar a que tengas la suficiente para hacerlo. Es probable que te valoren negativamente esta respuesta por ser ambigua y no resolver claramente la pregunta.

Comment: Ah no sabía eso, gracias por aclararme. Saludos =)